# One line of my script using all available memory - why?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP project I'm making, but I've hit a dead end as one line is causing the script to error out saying the memory limit has been exausted.

The line in question is part of a method, as follows:

```
public function query_all($query)
{

    if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) # Compatibility layer with PHP < 5.3
        $res = mysqli_fetch_all($this->query($query));
    else
    for ($res = array(); $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($this->query($query));) $res[] = $tmp;

    return $res;
}
```

This function is part of a class named Db, the line with the error is the line with the for loop:

```
for ($res = array(); $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($this->query($query));) $res[] = $tmp;
```

This function is only called once in my code, at the top of an else statement:

```
do
    {
        $id = rand(1000000, 9999999);

        if (!Util::in_array_r($id, $db->query_all('SELECT * FROM tickets')))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (true);

    $emailsubject = $db->escape($emailsubject);
    $emailbody = $db->escape($emailbody);
    $from = $db->escape($from);

    $db->query("INSERT INTO tickets VALUES ($id, '$emailsubject', '$emailbody', '$from')");


    foreach ($config['staff_emails'] as $email)
    {
        mail($email, "[$id] [NEW TICKET] $emailsubject", $emailbody, "Reply-to: $to");
    }
```

I don't understand why it is doing this - it never used to, and the only thing I changed was making all the SQL queries work :/

Does anyone know why this is happening? Could the for loop be running endlessly? The database contains only one row though, so I don't see how it could,

Thanks,
Liam

Comment: Don't use for() loop for fetching. `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(...) { $res[] = $row; }` is the preferred method. You're in somewhat undefined territory by initializing your loop counter as an array instead of an int, and termination condition as the result of a db operation.

Comment: Something I want to know, where does the $row variable come from?

Comment: it's just auto-created by php for you the first time the loop iterates.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop. You probably want to do

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->query($query)) {
    $res[] = $row;
```

instead of

```
for ($res = array(); $tmp = mysqli_fetch_array($this->query($query));) $res[] = $tmp;
```